# Convert pdf files to slideshow without Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, presentation-design

Is there a way to force an existing .pdf file to launch full-screen and auto-advance (prefereably with transitions) without owning Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: Microsoft Powerpoint or OpenOffice.org Impress. If you need specifics on how to do it with either let us know and I'm sure myself or someone else can help you out. Oh but it won't be a .pdf file - so that might be a deal breaker for this method. Not sure of any way besides Acrobat to do it with PDF format.

Comment: I wasn`t clear enough probably: the pdf`s are generated by various other programs, so powerpoint/impress can`t open them.

Answer (score 1):

One option I found is jPdf Tweak, an open-source program with rather unfriendly GUI and limited page-transition options. Does the job, however.

[image]

http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/